# Deny acces to any directory for everyone web.config

Tags: iis, web-config, directory

I wan't to deny acces to the directories for everyone in web.config. Is this possible? Or should be an Deny from ALL enough? I host this on a IIS server.

Comment: What's the point of a website no one can access?

Answer (score 0):

```
<location path="folder">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```